# How to check of which user-defined type a current JSON element is during $.each()?

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following structure for a JSON file:

```
({condos:[{Address:'123 Fake St.', Lat:'56.645654', Lng:'23.534546'},{... another condo ...},{...}],houses:[{Address:'1 Main Ave.', Lat:'34.765766', Lng:'27.8786674'},{... another house ...}, {...}]})
```

So, I have a list of *condos* and *houses* in one big JSON array.

I want to plot them all on my map, but I want to give *condos* and *houses* different marker icons( **blue** marker for *condos*, **green** marker for *houses* ).

Problem I have is - figuring out how to distinguish between types of markers when I `$.each()` through them. How would I use `if` to check whether I'm working with a *condo* or a *house* at the moment?

```
var markers = null;
$('#map').gmap(mapOptions).bind('init', function(){
    $.post('getMarkers.php', function(json){
        markers = json;
        $.each(markers, function(type, dataMembers) {
            $.each(dataMembers, function(i, j){
                //if house use house.png to create marker
                $('#map').gmap('addMarker', { 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(Lat), parseFloat(Lng)), 'bounds':true, 'icon':'house.png' } );
                //if condo use condo.png
                $('#map').gmap('addMarker', { 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(Lat), parseFloat(Lng)), 'bounds':true, 'icon':'condo.png' } );
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a nested collection - an object with two members (condos and houses), each containing multiple sub objects. You already seem to have the type as part of the outer `each()` loop, so just use it:

```
...
        markers = json;
        $.each(markers, function(type, dataMembers) { // <- right here
            $.each(dataMembers, function(i, j){
                if (type == 'house') {
                    $('#map').gmap('addMarker', { 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(Lat), parseFloat(Lng)), 'bounds':true, 'icon':'house.png' } );
                }
                else if (type == 'condo') {
                    $('#map').gmap('addMarker', { 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(Lat), parseFloat(Lng)), 'bounds':true, 'icon':'condo.png' } );
                }
            });
        });
...
```